# How to call particular node.js method from client side javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my application i have created many methods in node.js file.How can i call the particular method from client side javascript.

Below is my node.js file

```
        exports.method1=function(){

          }

        exports.method2=function(){

          }

         exports.method3=function(){

          }
```

Comment: You'd have to do it using AJAX, or an RPC such as: NowJS, or DNode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your client should send a message, for example:

```
socket.emit("callMethod", {"methodName":"method3"});
```

And in your server:

```
socket.on("callMethod", function(data) {
    if(data["methodName"] == "method3") {
        exports.method3();
    }
});
```

You don't call methods directly, you send events/messages.

Comment: For the people that would want more information regarding  [socket.io](http://socket.io/#how-to-use)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using sockets unless you really need to, from my experience they can be expensive. Sockets are great for intensive applications where a user stays engaged for awhile, otherwise I would suggest using a RESTful setup with javascript and node.js, for example:

http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-create-rest-api

this way the socket doesn't always have to be open which causes more overhead anyway. REST will use http requests whereas sockets you will have direct connection via TCP. REST is better if your app won't be constantly engaging a user, but rather have updates here and there.