# angular call a function from a form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, amazon-s3

I'm having a problem calling a function from angular - this function does two different things, uploading an image to s3 and saving the data from the form and the url of the image in s3 in mongo.
here is my html, so I called the fucntion ng-submit:

```
<form class="form-group" ng-submit="createActivity()">
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title:</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age:</label>
         <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" type="number" placeholder="Age" ng-model="age" min="0" max="16"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description:</label>
         <textarea class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" type="text" placeholder="Description" ng-model="description"></textarea>
         <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Themes:</label>
         <input type="radio" name="themes" value="frozen" ng-model="theme">frozen &nbsp;
         <input type="radio" name="themes" value="minions" ng-model="theme">minions &nbsp;
         <input type="radio" name="themes" value="heroes" ng-model="theme">heroes
         <input type="radio" name="themes" value="princess" ng-model="theme">princess &nbsp;
         <input type="radio" name="themes" value="piraets" ng-model="theme">piraets &nbsp;
         <input type="radio" name="themes" value="none" ng-model="theme">none 
         <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <br>
         <input type="file" name="upload" ng-model="image"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <br>
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="send"></input>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

and here is the function:

```
$scope.createActivity = function() {
var myUrl;

function(req, res) {
var ext, hash, form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
    files = [],
    fields = [];
form.keepExtensions = true;
form.uploadDir = 'tmp';
form.on('fileBegin', function(name, file) {
    ext = file.path.split('.')[1];
    hash = hasher();
    file.path = form.uploadDir + '/' + hash;
});
form.on('field', function(field, value) {
    fields.push([field, value]);
}).on('file', function(field, file) {
    files.push([field, file]);
}).on('end', function() {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../../tmp/' + hash, function(error, buf) {
        var req = client.put('/images/' + hash + '.png', {
            'x-amz-acl': 'private',
            'Content-Length': buf.length,
            'Content-Type': 'image/png'
        });
        console.log("hello");
        fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/../../downloads/' + hash + '.png', buf, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        });
        myUrl = req.url;
        req.on('response', function(res) {
            image.save(function(error, result) {
                if(error) {
                    console.error(error);
                } else {
                    response.redirect('http://' + request.headers.host + '/' + hash);
                };
            })
        });
        req.end(buf);
    });
});
form.parse(request);
activity.title = $scope.title;
activity.age = $scope.age;
activity.description = $scope.description;
activity.theme = $scope.theme;
activity.image = myUrl;
activity.$save(function(result) {
    $scope.activities.push(result);
    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.age = '';
    $scope.description = '';
    $scope.theme = '';
    $scope.image = myUrl;
});
}
}]);
```

I must say that individuality each function by itself work but when I put it in one function it doesn't. (I joined them together because I want both of them to be called from my form).

Answer (score 0):

The way we do it is via the function method like you describe:

```
...
formClickDoSomething() {
  this.functionOne();
  this.functionTwo();
  this.functionThree();
}
...
```

It should work, assuming as you say, all three functions work on their own.

Answer (score 0):

You should not join 2 functions in 1 like that. Keep the functions appart and call both from a different function for better readability. Here's a generic example :

```
function createActivity() {
    doSomethingFirst();
    doSomethingNext();
}

function doSomethingFirst() {
    // your code for first function
}

function doSomethingNext() {
    // your code for next function
}
```

Or if you call your second function after a successCallback from first function, you can do something like this :

```
function createActivity() {
    // your code for first function
    if (success) {
        doSomethingNext();
    } else {
        // show error
    }
}

function doSomethingNext() {
    // your code for next function
}
```

Comment: and if I want to call a function form server (node.js) to client side function(that is $scope.createActivity()) how do I do that?

Comment: I think this is well answered in another thread : [How to call particular node.js method from client side javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359105/how-to-call-particular-node-js-method-from-client-side-javascript)

Comment: Hi I didnt anderstend the answer there can you halp me?